# Syntax Error in MVC5 is preventing other JavaScript from functioning

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC5 and KendoUI This code throws no errors on build and works as expected, BUT it throws an error in the chrome console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >"

This prevents an upload button I have on the page from functioning. Can I get around this?

```
    if( @{Model.ticketInputNumber} > 0){
        $('#ticketResults').toggleClass('hidden');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around as such:

```
 var True = "True";
 var False = "False";
 var x = @Model.validNumber;
 if( x != False){
   $('#ticketResults').toggleClass('hidden');
  };
```